# Connect S7000 to an external monitor for real-time view

Tags: nikon, live-view

When I connect my Nikon S7000 to a TV using an HDMI cable, I can view the pictures previously taken (playback mode).

However, I cannot have the view from the camera played to the TV in real time. It seems that plugging the HDMI cable in forces the playback mode.

**How can I switch to "shooting" mode to have the real-time image on my TV?**

I know I could record a movie then use the playback mode, but that's not real-time.

Comment: I have no idea but take a look at this: http://nikonrumors.com/2013/05/11/free-open-source-tethering-software-for-nikon-dslr-cameras.aspx/ and this: http://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/article/hcxs08cw/remotely-taking-photographs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I switch to "shooting" mode to have the real-time image on my TV?

According to the [manual](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/205/COOLPIX_S7000.html), you can't.

The manual for the S7000 gives no indication that live view mode is supported over HDMI, and in fact the troubleshooting section lists *Cannot switch to shooting mode* as a potential problem, with the solution: *Disconnect the HDMI cable or USB cable.*

Contrast that with the manual for the D7000, which explains that connecting a HDMI cable will disable the on-camera screen and show the view through the lens on the connected display.

Having looked at the manuals for the S7000 and D7000, it seems pretty clear that if the S7000 supported live view over HDMI, the manual would tell you as much. The fact that it doesn't is a clear indication that the feature is not supported on the S7000.

Comment: Ok. But I found somewhere the specification "hd video out: yes". Was that actually only for viewing recorded video?

Comment: @fffred It certainly looks that way. And it's not *wrong* -- the camera does have an HDMI port after all -- but I can see how that would seem misleading if you were hoping for live video.